# Как сопоставить датасет и словарь по индексам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Есть датасет `Glres` и словарь `folds`.

```
folds = {}
folds['test'] = data['Res'].iloc[testfrom:testto]
```

> выше пример заполнения folds. type(folds) - dict

Нужно все значения колонки словаря `folds['test']` вставить в колонку датасета `Glres['Tst_cls']` в соответствии с ключами `folds['test']`. Номер строки = номер ключа.

```
Glres['Tst_cls'] = folds['test']
```

Так работает, но для тех строк, которым нет соответствующих ключей в  `folds['test']` в `Glres['Tst_cls']` проставляются `Nan`

Может быть это конечно просто, но ответ так нигде и не нашла.

Прикладываю файлы: Pandas столбец, [словарь столбец и результат](https://yadi.sk/d/EhF9-_PavUW2TQ).

[image: Заменить значения в соответствии с индексами]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое заработало:

```
Glres['Tst_cls'].iloc[folds['test'].index] = folds['test']
```

тип `folds['test']` оказался `pandas.core.series.Series` :) несмотря на то что сам `folds` это `dict`. Не знала, что так можно

если есть какое-либо более красивое и грамотное решение буду признательна!

Answer (score 1):

После обновления вопроса оказалось, что в словаре `folds` по ключу `test` содержится Pandas.Series со значениями, поэтому с `folds["test"]` можно работать как с обычным Pandas.Series:

```
Glres.loc[folds["test"].index, 'Tst_cls'] = folds['test']
```

Comment: ошиблась с вопросом :) у меня колонка словаря из которой нужно взять данные и колонка датафрейма, куда нужно вставить данные, в соответствии с индексами колонки словаря. При использовании 'Glres.loc[folds.index, 'Tst_cls'] = folds['test']' выдает AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, приведите пожалуйста воспроизводимые примеры данных в вопросе

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, кстати , что значит колонка словаря? ;)

Comment: приложила.Картинка также дает информацию того что хочу на выходе. А колонка словаря :) это данные(по аналогии со столюцом в pd dataframe), не знаю, как их правильно называют.

Comment: Я знаю в словаре только ключи и их значения)

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, я все еще не очень себе представляю как выглядит ваш словарь - можете привести строку Python кода для создания словаря? Судя по вашему `Dict.csv` - это у вас все таки DataFrame, поэтому нет смысла публиковать еще одно решение, которое вам опять не подойдет, потому, что ваш словарь выглядит не так как я себе его представил)

Comment: поправила первый вопрос. :) folds = {}
folds['test'] = data['Res'].iloc[testfrom:testto]